# Variables and exponents

Tags: exponentiation

How would you solve this equation ?

$$500n=4000(1.016)^n$$

I tried using some logarithms but I could not do it. The only unknown variable is n but I'm having a bit of trouble getting there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The practical way to solve such equations is to *approximate the solution numerically*. There's no expression for the solution in terms of elementary functions.

You *can* write down a solution explicitly using [Lambert's W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) as
$$ n = - \frac{W(-\frac{4000}{500} \ln(1.016))}{\ln(1.016)} $$
but that's hardly enlightening since the $W(a)$ is itself defined as "the solution to $xe^x=a$", which has a similar form to your original equation.

Numerically, Wolfram Alpha finds the solutions $n\approx9.26787$ and $n\approx 204.047$.

Comment: Thanks, the solution and explanation is great!